# Posting sensitive data to an external url

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, model-view-controller, sha256

I have a requirement to post form data to an external third party. The client has suggested the data to be secured using SHA-256. They want us to hash the value so they can verify the integrity and authentication of the data.

We are using .net MVC. 
The data will be sent over https.

Given the example form in the view:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="@Model.ExternalUrl">
   <input type="hidden" name="title" value="@Model.Title" />
   <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="@Model.FirstName" />
   <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="@Model.LastName" />
   <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Assuming that javascript code calls the submit of the button for an automatic redirect, what is the best way to hash the data?

At the moment i'm contemplating calling the server, get the hashed data from the .net HMACSHA256 class, returning the data to the client and then posting this data to the external url?

Interested in hearing some constructive opinion on this, ultimately we want to avoid creating latency for the user.

N.B. Open to other security suggestions with the main objective being to verify data integrity and authentication from a client side post, i did, however, want to avoid making the question too open.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. My suggestion: use SSL (https protocol). For authentication, set additional input fields (or better cookie). Or create registered client certificate.

Comment: If you want integrity, then CryptoJS or Spark (JS) provide SHA1 implementations. Data authentication suggests that you have some shared secret on the client. Do you have one? What form does it have? If you don't have one, then you need to make the call to your service prior to sending the request to the third party service.

Comment: @VikciaR I don't really see how the question is very unclear, i stated in the question that we are already using https protocol. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @ArtjomB. If we are sending this over https, would we then also need to validate the integrity or does the fact that the data is sent encrypted imply this? I did take a look at cryptojs but i think SHA1 is being heavily phased out. We have no shared secret as of yet but i think something like that could work for us, I'm unsure how to implement a client side shared private key whilst maintaining security. In its simplest form we would want to stamp the key into the post to send it over but surely that exposes it to the client user? Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions

Comment: Nearly all [TLS ciphersuites](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-C) define a MAC (see also [this](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4)). So you won't need to do it yourself. Note that GCM and CCM already include message authenticity.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Very useful information, many many thanks. :)